# Quick way to add Stopwatch.start and Stopwatch.end to all functions vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, stopwatch

Just trying to look at a quick way to find the timings for each individual function in my application.  Would like to optimize code and see if some function is taking longer than others but was wondering if there was some quick way i could add the Stopwatch.start and Stopwatch.end to the beginning and ending of each function.  Could someone assist me in what to google?  I can see how I want it to work but have no clue on how to start.

Not looking for answers, just guidance :)

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a "profiler".

Comment: Use a "Profiler" is the right answer but if you did want to add a stopwatch to each method call you could use Aspect Oriented Programming (see for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReSharper (or something similar) to create a macro for your functions that would include the stopwatch code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select-case block in your class.  Use an enum to call the functions by name.  The select block can then run the correct function according to the enum value.  It'll be rather long but you only need the stopwatch calls around the select block and they will get called for each function.